# How to run coroutines in cucumber?

Tags: kotlin, cucumber, coroutine, mockserver

I am using kotlin and cucumber. I made a simple mokeserver that I would like to run in my tests. I wanted to start running it in a step in the background without the test getting stuck on the step. I honestly have no idea how to do it, I am not very good with coroutines

Comment: Steps are in order within a scenario. What is your idea? I believe cucumber step is blocking by definition.

Comment: I wanted the server to run in the background. If I didn't have to use cucumber I would just run it on different coroutines. However I am not sure how to do it with cucumber